# Opera hides empty containers

Tags: html, css, opera

On my page, I need to render a set of justified containers. A grid is desighed to hold 6 elements, and to keep elements in place in case of where there's less than 6 of them, there's ghost elements.

```
- items.in_groups_of(6, :ghost) do |group|
  .catalog-line
    - group.each do |item|
      - if item == :ghost
        .catalog-item.ghost
      - elsif item == highlighted_item
        .catalog-item
          .img-outline.highlighted
            .shadow-circle
              %img.circle{src: item.picture.small.url, alt: item.name}
          %p= item.name
      - else
        %a.catalog-item{href: show_catalog_item_path(item)}
          .img-outline
            .shadow-circle
              %img.circle{src: item.picture.small.url, alt: item.name}
          %p= item.name
```

Everything works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but Opera for some reason doesn't want to mind those empty containers when justifying them, so if there's 3, they're spaced too far from each other, taking all width of the .catalog-line and ignoring ghosts.

What makes me scratch my head is that ghost div's actually there in DOM structure, with width set equal to real container but Opera takes them as non-existent and Dragonfly inspect tool doesn't show their positions or borders, only css attributes.

CSS properties of .catalog-line

```
font-size: 0px;
line-height: 0px;
text-align: justify;
display: block;
```

CSS properties of .catalog-item

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
width: 144px;
color: #333333;
zoom: 1;
font-size: 0px;
line-height: 0px;
```

I really don't want to reconsider my ghost block system, I wish I just could make Opera somehow recognize them.

EDIT: Html

```
<div class="catalog-line">
  <a class="catalog-item" href="/asm-elit/divany">
    <div class="img-outline">
      <div class="shadow-circle">
        <img alt="Диваны" class="circle" src="/system/category_pictures/5290f7371d41c8351a00000f/small_divans.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Диваны</p>
  </a>
  <a class="catalog-item" href="/asm-elit/krovati">
    <div class="img-outline">
      <div class="shadow-circle">
        <img alt="Кровати" class="circle" src="/system/category_pictures/5290f7381d41c8351a000010/small_beds.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Кровати</p>
  </a>
  <a class="catalog-item" href="/asm-elit/kresla">
    <div class="img-outline">
      <div class="shadow-circle">
        <img alt="Кресла" class="circle" src="/system/category_pictures/5290f7381d41c8351a000011/small_armchairs.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Кресла</p>
  </a>
  <div class="catalog-item ghost" style="height:10px;"></div>
  <div class="catalog-item ghost" style="height:10px;"></div>
  <div class="catalog-item ghost" style="height:10px;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS for .img-outline

```
background-color: white;
border-bottom-color: gray;
border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
border-bottom-style: dashed;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-left-color: gray;
border-left-style: dashed;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-color: gray;
border-right-style: dashed;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-top-color: gray;
border-top-left-radius: 50%;
border-top-right-radius: 50%;
border-top-style: dashed;
border-top-width: 1px;
padding-bottom: 6px;
padding-left: 6px;
padding-right: 6px;
padding-top: 6px;
width: 130px;
display: block;
```

CSS for .shadow-circle

```
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: auto;
height: auto;
```

CSS for p:

```
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
padding: 5px 0;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
```

Other elements only have inherited properties.

Update: it seems to be something wrong with .ghost . Even putting actual picture there, preserving element structure from normal blocks, doesn't work. Seems to be something I unaware I can't find any crucial difference in CSS or somewhere else.

Another update: after setting .ghost exactly like regular element and making itself a link, I discowered that they started to appear - out of screen and out of their parent container as if that paren was twice as wide. WHY, Opera?

Comment: can you stick a blank space in them `&nbsp;` and see if it forces them to show up?

Comment: I tried, but misteriously, it doesn't work too! Nor even transforming .ghost div to a link like a regular block.